# Add Photo library to Sharepoint 2013 via powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I need to add a new Photo Library in sharepoint 2013.  I have most of the script, but need some help with the template type.

Here is the script

```
enter code here
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=add-sp$true)]
[string]$Web,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$ListTitle,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$ListUrl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string]$Description,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Template
)
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Web
**$listTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates[$Template]**
$SPWeb.Lists.Add($ListUrl,$Description,$listTemplate)
$list = $SPWeb.Lists[$ListUrl]
$list.Title = $ListTitle
$list.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```

Stop-SPAssignment -Global

Above the $listTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates[$Template] line is bold because this is where the issue is.  When I run the script I am passing in the string "Library"  The issue is that the $listTemplate variable is null and fails on the next line.

Is there a different value for the $Template parameter?  What else am I possibly doing wrong?

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 0):

The template type that should be passed in is "Picture Library".  All other code stays the same.